# Cannot use import statement outside a module Express.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to connect my model named 'category' with my 'item' model, but I get this error that won't allow me to import it. I cannot use require because ES doesn't support it and it suggests me to use import instead.

Code:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
import descData from "./category";

const itemSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  created: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
  },
  category: [descData],
  quantity: {
    type: [String],
    required: true,
  },
});

var itemData = mongoose.model("itemData", itemSchema);
module.exports = itemData;
```

And here's my category code:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const descSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  descripton: {
    type: String,
  },
});

var descData = mongoose.model("descData", descSchema);
module.exports = descData;
```

Here's also a screenshot of error[image: error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

either you use import notation for everything (but you would need to set "type": "module" in your package.json, and export properly in your module files)

or you use require notation everywhere

which means you should do that :

```
const descData = require("./category");
```

here is an exemple of schema in schema. you can see that you dont put the model in the schema, but the schema in the schema.

```
const childSchema = new Schema({ name: 'string' });

const parentSchema = new Schema({
  // Array of subdocuments
  children: [childSchema],
  // Single nested subdocuments. Caveat: single nested subdocs only work
  // in mongoose >= 4.2.0
  child: childSchema
});
```

Comment: But then i get an error: "`model` is not a valid type within the array `category`" refering to mongoose.model(....)

Comment: i think in your category file you shoudl do : module.exports = descSchema; because mongoose want a schema

Answer (score 0):

You are using 'CommonJs' module and ES6 module patterns together which is not a viable solution. You should opt to imports/exports that is provided by ES6.

You can make it available by adding `type: "module"` in your package.json. Also, you now need to use `export` instead of `module.exports`. There are two exports ways: named exports and default export. Check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export) for more details.

In your js file make a change:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import descData from "./category";

const itemSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  created: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
  },
  category: [descData],
  quantity: {
    type: [String],
    required: true,
  },
});

const itemData = mongoose.model("itemData", itemSchema);
export default itemData;
```

Comment: wont work since the rest of the files are still using require syntax.

Comment: Definitely, it should either follow commonjs or es6 in the whole project.